# Filter Array by month and get the total sum for each month using javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, object

I have an array that holds multiple objects and each object has a date, amount and id as keys.
I'd like to group all the objects by month and then return the sum of the amount keys for each month.

Here's my first approach but I'm pretty sure it's not the right way to go.
I'm manually defining the Start and the End of each month.

Is there another way to do this more dynamically ?
1 - Get the start and end of each month
2 - Group the array by month without using lodash ( I'm open to use moment.js )
3 - Sum the values of each month
3 - Return the name of the month + the total

**The Array structure in json**

```
  "expenses": [
    {
      "amount": 5.97,
      "date": "09/01/2022",
      "id": 1
    },
]
```

**The Logic in React**

```
const MonthsTotal = ({ expenses }) => {
  let novemberTotal = 0;
  let decemberTotal = 0;

  expenses
    .filter((items) => {
      return items.date >= "11/01/2022" && items.date <= "11/31/2022";
    })
    .forEach((item) => {
      novemberTotal += item.amount;
    });

  expenses
    .filter((items) => {
      return items.date >= "12/01/2022" && items.date <= "12/31/2022";
    })
    .forEach((item) => {
      decemberTotal += item.amount;
    });
```

**The output in react**
This is how I'm outputting the data

```
return (
 <Box>
  <Card variant="outlined">
    <div> November </div>
    <div>{novemberTotal}</div>
  </Card>
 </Box>

 <Box>
  <Card variant="outlined">
    <div>December</div>
    <div>{decemberTotal}</div>
  </Card>
 </Box>
)
export default MonthsTotal;
```

Comment: What is the ideal output you're hoping to achieve? An array of objects? A single object?

Answer (score 0):

I would first group the expenses by their month and they sum up their amount.
In this example I've used lodash and date-fns, but feel free to replace them with any other library.

```js
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import groupBy from 'lodash/groupBy';
import sumBy from 'lodash/sumBy';

const expenses = [
  {
    amount: 5.97,
    date: '09/01/2022',
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    amount: 5.97,
    date: '09/02/2022',
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    amount: 5.97,
    date: '10/01/2022',
    id: 3,
  },
];

const groups = groupBy(expenses, (entry) => {
  return format(new Date(entry.date), 'LLLL');
});

const months = Object.entries(groups).map((entry) => {
  const [key, values] = entry;

  return {
    name: key,
    total: sumBy(values, 'amount'),
  };
});

// [
//   { name: 'September', total: 11.94 },
//   { name: 'October', total: 5.97 }
// ]
```

Next, you can pass all months to your React component and just loop over them

```
function MonthsTotal(props) {
  const { months } = props;

  return (
    <>
      {months.map((month) => (
        <Box key={month.name}>
          <Card variant="outlined">
            <div>{month.name}</div>
            <div>{month.total}</div>
          </Card>
        </Box>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

<MonthsTotal months={months} />;
```